# How to use pv to see decompression progress?

Tags: compression, tar

I've seen: [How to use Pipe Viewer (pv) for measuring compression progress?](https://superuser.com/questions/508615/how-to-use-pipe-viewer-pv-for-measuring-compression-progress)

Is there a way to do the same thing for decompressing a gzipped file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this does the trick:

```
 pv file.tgz | tar xzf - -C target_directory
```